# Why can't the Data Annotations 'UrlAttribute' recognize IP aliases?

Tags: .net, validation, url, data-annotations

I have a model that had it's properties validated manually, and is now being refactored to work with Data Annotations attributes.

There is a string property in the model that is a configurable Url to a server.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Url]
    public string ServerAddress {get; set;}
}
```

Something like this is perfectly valid as it's value on our scenario:

`"http://localhost/Test"`

This turns out to be an invalid Url for the default [`UrlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.urlattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) validation though, and I get the standard error message:

> The ServerAddress field is not a valid fully-qualified http, https, or
>   ftp URL

Isn't the above example a valid url for some reason? What am I missing? The attribute constructor doesn't seem to support any customization options too, so I'm kind of stuck unless I create my own implementation of the Url validation (which I would obviously like to avoid unless absolutely necessary).

If I use the IP addresses directly instead, it works as expected, like `127.0.0.1`. Yet, this is unacceptable in our case.

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707546/774575).

Answer (score 0):

At a guess (away from code now), I'm thinking its the lack of a .com / .net etc, because of the localhost?

You might try: http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Url/Create