# Url validation attribute marks `localhost` as invalid Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

In our ASP.MVC project we are using DataAnnotations attributes for validation. One of the fields should contains Url and it is marked with `[Url]` attribute. But if I put `http://localhost:13030` into the field value it isn't passing the validation.

Is there any way to use the attribute to define `localhost` as a valid target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UrlAttribute` validates against the RegEx shown in the source code here: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs#L46.

`http://localhost` doesn't match due to its lack of a `.`.

See this answer for other options: [How I can validate urls in C# for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599205/how-i-can-validate-urls-in-c-sharp-for-localhost).

EDIT: According to the source code, you could add `dataAnnotations:dataTypeAttribute:disableRegEx` to your AppSettings and set its value to `true`. This would cause the `UrlAttribute` validation process to **only** check that it begins with `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://`. See [Line 33](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs#L33) of the same source file for that.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon [Kirk Larkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707546/1525756): The `"dataAnnotations:dataTypeAttribute:disableRegEx"` app setting is only available since .NET Framework 4.6.1, according to [dotnet pull request #668 (re-add ASPNET472CompatDoc)](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/pull/668/files).

I also checked by downloading the .NET Framework 4.6 [(58 MB .zip)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/dotnet46.zip) and 4.6.1 RTM [(59 MB .zip)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/dotnet461RTM.zip) source and running the following `git diff` command.

```
git diff D:/src/dotnet46/Source/ndp/fx/src/xsp/system/DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs D:/src/dotnet461RTM/Source/ndp/fx/src/xsp/system/DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs
```

Indeed, the new-as-of-4.6.1 `internal static class AppSettings` is what reads the new-as-of-4.6.1 app setting.

And ... My point in adding this answer is that I am out of luck on net452.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "127.0.0.1" instead "localhost". E.g http://127.0.0.1:13030